# Changing a row horizontal alignment

Tags: tables

I do have a table that that different languages is used in table rows (one left-to-right and one right-to-left), the table is like this:
[image: the table]

and the code for the table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{13cm}|}
\hline
 $a = 2$\\\hline
$b \leftarrow a$\\\hline
خروجی برابر است.
\\\hline
\end{tabular} 
\caption{جدول نمونه}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How could i left align the first two rows of the table?

Comment: Can you make your code into a complete (minimal) working document, including `\documentclass` and the necessary packages and font definitions?

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I know its probably late and i am  truly sorry sorry for that, but i edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that. It works with XeLaTeX. If you want to use LuaLaTeX, the replace `bidi` with `luabidi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{persian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\usepackage{bidi} % luabidi if you use lualatex

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{13cm}|}
  \hline
  \setLTR $a = 2$\\\hline
  \setLTR $b \leftarrow a$\\\hline
  \setRTL  خروجی برابر است.
  \\\hline
  \end{tabular} 
\caption{جدول نمونه}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]